# How do I get System.Web.Http.Owin?

Tags: .net, owin

I had a version number problem with system.web.http.owin.

So I removed it from my projects package references, with the idea that I would re-added it to see if it fixed the problem. However it has disappeared completely. I.e. in visual studio if I go:

solution explorer > myProject > references > RMC > add reference >

and then search for `system.web.http.owin` it doesn't appear.

Any ideas what has gone wrong or what package I need to install to make it re-appear.

My original error message...

> Error 7   Assembly 'System.Web.Http.Owin, Version=5.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses
>   'System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  e:\user\project1\src\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin.5.1.1\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.Owin.dll Smots.Core

Answer (score 105):

The NuGet package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin) contains that DLL.

You can install it by right-clicking on the References folder of your project and selecting "Manage NuGet Packages..." and searching for "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin". Or you can use the Package Manager Console and type the following:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
```

If you use the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio, be sure you have the intended project selected in the drop down labeled "Default project:" That is easy to overlook.

Comment: Using the console doesn't seem to work well. I was only able to get the package to install correctly in VS2015 using the GUI.