# Can't find ApplicationOAuthProvider and HostAuthenticationFilter

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Their use is described in at least a few articles (i.e. [http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)) on WebApi 2 authorization, but I can't find what reference I need to have them included. I do have references to Microsoft.Owin/Owin.Security/Owin.Security.OAuth.

Help?

Answer (score 4):

I have resolve HostAuthenticationFilter issue by installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin package.

Please also check
[How do I get System.Web.Http.Owin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690845/how-do-i-get-system-web-http-owin)

Answer (score 2):

by default it placed in `Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` in root folder of your Project
`ApplicationOAuthProvider` inherit from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class.
here is it implemention  :

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        //TODO: Pull from configuration
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(publicClientId));
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager();

        var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(null);
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```